# Python: Why is the content of the file deleted when I save the changes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have `test_final.txt` with some simple words on it, a couples of sentences. I want to use `shuffle` method as to mix the words. The very big problem is that, after running the code, my `test_final.txt` becomes empty. The second problem, I don't know why is not working the `Shuffle` method.

```
import random
import re 
import sys
f = open("test_final.txt", "r")
print(f.read())

mama = r"([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)"
listOfWords = re.findall(mama, 'f')
print("Result: ", listOfWords)

random.Random(4).shuffle(listOfWords)
print("Shuffled stuff: ", listOfWords)


finalString = ""
for cuvant in listOfWords: 
    finalString = finalString + cuvant + " "
finalString = finalString.strip()
print(finalString)

#SAve

with open("test_final.txt", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:

   file.write(finalString)
```

- For example I have some words into **`test_final.txt`**:

`my book is still here`, the output should be something like this
`still book here is my`.

- After running the code, the **`test_final.txt`** becomes empty. (The problem is from save method. But, also, if I test without `save` , it doesn't mix the word as I need with Shuffle Method

Comment: `listOfWords = re.findall(mama, 'f')` - can you explain what is the meaning of 'f'?

Comment: You are opening the very same file in read mode in your fourth line and never closing it. So either call `f.close()` after reading it or use a `with`

Comment: `f` is from `f = open("test_final.txt", "r")` (I try to make the connection with the file)

Comment: Please [edit] to show a sample input file and explain what results you actually want.

Comment: I update the post

Comment: Do you want to keep the lines that are not shuffled or do you want to output only shuffled lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has multiple problems.

```py
print(f.read())
```

prints the lines to standard output, and leaves the file handle at the end of the file.  If you try to read anything more from `f` now, you will get an empty string.

Because you are reading the lines without storing them anywhere, or generating any new lines in the subsequent code (see below), *of course* you are not writing anything to the new file in the end.

```py
mama = r"([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)"
listOfWords = re.findall(mama, 'f')
```

searches the static string `'f'` for words followed by a space and a sequence of numbers; of course, `'f'` doesn't contain any spaces or numbers, so `listOfWords` ends up empty.  Did you mean to read from the variable `f` here? Though that won't work either; `findall` expects a string, not a file handle, as its second argument.

As already pointed out elsewhere, leaving `f` open while you attempt to overwrite the same file is not going to work reliably.  You will want to close `f` before you attempt to write to the same file.

It's not clear why you call `random.Random(4)`; I will simply assume that you want the list to be shuffled randomly, using an even distribution.

As per your problem description, you want the list of words to contain the words from the file as separate strings. Your current code doesn't do anything like that, but it's easy enough to do; just `split` the line and add that to your list.

Guessing rather wildly as to what you might actually want, try the following.

```py
import random
import re 
# import sys  # unused import


# Changed the regex so that it can actually match words
mama = r"[a-zA-Z]+\d*"

# Python variables should prefer snake_case over headlessCamelCase
list_of_words = []
# Specify encoding here, too
with open("test_final.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        for word in line.rstrip('\n').split():
            # Does this line match the regular expression?
            if re.match(mama, word):
                list_of_words.append(word)
            else:
                # Print a warning when we are discarding a line
                print('# discarding', word)

print("Result: ", list_of_words)

random.shuffle(list_of_words)
print("Shuffled stuff: ", list_of_words)

finalString = " ".join(list_of_words)
print(finalString)

with open("test_final.txt", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as file:
   file.write(finalString)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/fBXb8v

I'll still note that the code rearranges the file to put everything on a single line, with spaces between the strings we read line by line from the original file. This seems potentially destructive; I would keep on separate lines whatever was read in on separate lines, just to make the process stable and repeatable.

Comment: is the same thing, is deletes the text file after running the code. and doesn't make the Shuffle (mix words)

Comment: That's an improvement, thanks. Could you still explain what the regex is supposed to do? Your example text does indeed not match the regex.

Comment: See update regarding `split()` now. Going forward, try to ask one well-defined question per post.

Comment: same result... is empty my file after run the code, and Shuffle doesn't work (I test it without save the file)

Comment: I can't repro that; the code works for me. See the demo link now.

Comment: What does _"I test it without save the file"_ mean?

Comment: no no, I see now. You didn;t update the code from answer. But the code from DEMO https://ideone.com/fBXb8v is WORKING. thanks. Please update the code from answer

Comment: Wow, you do like helping people.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the file to save it.

file.close()

Comment: I try also with `file.close()` but this method also empty my text file instead of mixing the words and save the new modifyes

Answer (score 0):

At the begining of the script your open file and read it. You don't close it afterwards. Trying using `with` to open your first file

```
import random
import re 
import sys
with open("test_final.txt", "r", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)

mama = r"([a-zA-Z]+) (\d+)"
listOfWords = re.findall(mama, 'f')
print("Result: ", listOfWords)

random.Random(4).shuffle(listOfWords)
print("Shuffled stuff: ", listOfWords)


finalString = ""
for cuvant in listOfWords: 
    finalString = finalString + cuvant + " "
finalString = finalString.strip()
print(finalString)

#SAve

with open("test_final.txt", "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
   f.write(finalString)
```

Comment: is the same thing, is deletes the text file after running the code. and doesn't make the Shuffle (mix words)

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to read and to write same file. Doesn't work like this.
Opening file for writing will overwrite file from the start. You can open file
for writing in append mode, than data will be appended to the end of the file, but I guess this is not what you want. Usually if you want to change file you will need to write a new one (and then replace old one by new one if you like).

And, as mentioned above it is better to close file after reading.

Comment: hello, I don;t understand. Maybe you should write a code solution.

Comment: I most certainly shouldn't do anything at all. As you can see from other answers no one understands what are you trying to do. Adding sample input and sample output will greatly help people that do want to write a code solution  - @triplee looks both willing and very thorough